# Multivariable Calculus: How to conclude the domain for x and y?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am self-learning multivariable calculus for the first time, and I have this practice problem that I am not sure if my understanding is correct.

Suppose I have a multivariable function defined as $f(x,y)$ = $x^2$ + $y^2$, and its domain is D = {(x, y) s.t. $x^2$ + $y^2$$\le$1}.

I want to found out the domain for x and y individually.

I am not sure if I am correct, but I think in this case, the domain for x and y should be x $\in$ [0, 1] and y $\in$ [0, 1] since their sum can't be greater than 1.

Is my understanding correct in this case?

Comment: It turns out that in this case, you'll want to specify one in terms of the other to truly capture what's happening here-- for example, $(1,1)\notin D$ as $1^2+1^2\not\leq 1$. Also note that $x$ or $y$ could be negative.

Comment: @TheoC. I think OP is just asking for possible values for $x$ and $y$ individually, not as  pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @KaviRamaMurthy said, they can also take negative value.

As @TheoC. said, they can't simultaneously take numbers that $x^2+y^2>1$

In fact the domain of each of them is what "KaviRamaMurthy" said. But as they aren't independent variables, so when you choose one (foe example $x=t$) the other domain restricted ($y=\pm\sqrt{1-t^2}$).

Answer (score 0):

Both $x$ and $y$ range from $-1$ to $1$. There is no reason for them to be $\geq 0$.